# Extract 11-character alphanumeric identifier from setence

Tags: powerquery

I am attempting to extract an 11-character identifier from an imported sentence.  The identifier is as combination of numbers and letters in a specific sequence. Presumably, it will separated by spaces both before and after the identifier.  I had previously created something similar in VBA, but now trying to do this in Power Query. Any ideas?

Snippet from VBA code for 11-character identifier is as follows:

```
Array("[1-9]", "[AC-HJKMNPQRT-Y]", "[AC-HJKMNPQRT-Y0-9]", "[0-9]", "[AC-HJKMNPQRT-Y]", _
        "[AC-HJKMNPQRT-Y0-9]", "[0-9]", "[AC-HJKMNPQRT-Y]", "[AC-HJKMNPQRT-Y]", "[0-9]", "[0-9]")
```

Code above illustrates the first character is a number between 1 and 9, then second character is a number between 0 and 9 or letter outlined as AC-HJKMNPQRT-Y, and so on.

Anyway, seems like PQ can't do regex, so any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Regex is not native to PQ, but can be easily implemented using Python, R or JS.  Python and R are available when using Power BI desktop.  In Excel, you can use JS.  See [Regex in Power BI and Power Query in Excel with Java Script](http://www.thebiccountant.com/2018/04/25/regex-in-power-bi-and-power-query-in-excel-with-java-script/) and [this code at github](https://gist.github.com/Hugoberry/4948d96b45d6799c47b4b9fa1b08eadf)

Comment: The various text functions are also available in PQ and could probably be used to return your desired results. This may or may not execute more efficiently.

Comment: Thanks.  Was able to use the Javascript Regex function to make it work.